# why does Rails think Model attribute is a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake-task

This is a custom rake task file, if that makes a difference.

I want to pull all user_id's from Pupil, and apply them to get the User.id for all pupils.

It happily prints out line 2 with correct user_id, but then considers user_id a 'method' and breaks on line 3. Why? Where is my mistake?

```
        course_pupils = Pupil.where(course_id: study.course_id)
        course_pupils.map { |a| puts a.user_id }
        pupils = User.where(id: course_pupils.user_id )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

course_pupils is still a relation when you are calling it in line 3. Line 2 is non destructive (and if it was, it would turn it into an array of nils because `puts` returns nil).

You need to do:

```
pupils = User.where(id: course_pupils.pluck(:user_id) )
```

Or something like that

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, you cannot call an instance method `user_id` on a collection, try this instead

```
user_ids = Pupil.where(course_id: study.course_id).pluck(:user_id)
pupils = User.where(id: user_ids )
```

Hope that helps!